# How do I get a TP-LINK WN723N wireless USB adapter working?

Tags: 12.04, wireless

I am having trouble using a TP-LINK WN723N wireless USB adapter on my computer which is running Ubuntu 12.04.  When I plug the adapter in, the computer automatically picks up a signal from my wireless router but only connects to the internet for a short amount of time before losing the connection.

I have searched for additional drivers and have tried running the .exe installation file on the WINE drive with no such luck... Am very new to Ubuntu would love some help! Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1):

Its probably a bad signal, or signal interference. As far as plug and play adapters for linux it doesn't get much simpler than the Tp link; I fiddled around with it for like an hour just to figure out it was already installed, I didn't expect it to be so easy. I too lost connection many many times but it was mainly due to interference as the problem was solved when I moved to a different residence,, how short a time frame you talking about and does the amount of time vary. Do you have a television or microwave between your computer and the source signal?